# Is there a way to return a null row in a linq query if the where clause is false

Tags: c#, linq

I have a query with a statement that goes like this :

```
join pp in List on bp.Id equals pp.BilletProduitId into bob
                     from x in bob.DefaultIfEmpty()
                     where x.GAId is 1
```

For now if GAId is not 1 my row is not returned which makes sense. But I would like it to return a null row insteed so that I would know that WHERE statement was false.

Comment: If you don't want to filter out rows that don't meet that condition then *don't filter out rows that don't meet that condition*.

Comment: You know a WHERE clause was false if a row was not returned.

Comment: It seems like you want a compound left join criteria.  You can do that with anonymous types like `on new {bp.Id, GAId = 1} equals { Id = pp.BilletProduitID, pp.GAId}`  or filter `List` before using it in the join.

Comment: The thing is I don't have those rows in my database, Sometimes I have them sometimes I don't. I already know when I do , but I need to know when I don't. The GAId can go from 1 to 4 and depending on which one I put it in a different variable. Can I put this variable to null if it's not in the database.

Answer (score -1):

I asume you want to do a SQL *LEFT JOIN*.

`.DefaultIfEmpty()` should work fine. Check whether it is at the correct possition (collection / table).

For more information please read the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/linq/perform-left-outer-joins).